# Firebase won't run with iOS simulator. Flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, simulator

as I said in the title I'm not able to run iOS simulator with Firecloud.
If I only add Firebase_core package to pubspec.yaml all works fine, but when I add cloud_firestore: ^3.1.5 I got this error:

P.s. With Android simulator all works fine.

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            9.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
/Users/luca/Desktop/prova/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/third_party/upb/upb/port.c:2:10: fatal error: 'upb/port_def.inc' file not found
#include "upb/port_def.inc"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
/Users/luca/Desktop/prova/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/third_party/upb/upb/msg.c:2:10: fatal error: 'upb/msg.h' file not found
#include "upb/msg.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order
/Users/luca/Desktop/prova/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
/Users/luca/Desktop/prova/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
/Users/luca/Desktop/prova/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
/Users/luca/Desktop/prova/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')
/Users/luca/Desktop/prova/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
/Users/luca/Desktop/prova/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.

Can anyone help me? I am stuck with this error since 2 weeks ago :S
thanks to all.

Comment: Change / Update your deployment target to a minimum of 9.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have already modified pod file with minimum version of 9 and also 10 without results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in your pod file

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
         if config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'].to_f < 9.0
           config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
         end
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           101.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
 ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/luca/Desktop/prova/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/third_party/upb/upb/port.c:2:10: fatal error: 'upb/port_def.inc' file not found
    #include "upb/port_def.inc"
1 error generated.
    /Users/luca/Desktop/prova/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/third_party/upb/upb/msg.c:2:10: fatal error: 'upb/msg.h' file not found
   #include "upb/msg.h"

Comment: Still not able to run the app on iOS simulator.
The app I'm talking about is just the example app when you start a new project with flutter but with cloud_firestore and firebase_core packages

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try this: 
1. delete ios folder
2. flutter clean
3. flutter create . 
4. pod init
5. pod install

Comment: SOLVED! Thx Nazmul for the support. I did the follow:

In pod file just remove comments in target iOS version and changed it to 10. Then I had to delete the cache folder of cocoapods (~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods). Now all works “fine”. Over 500s vs the 20s of android to run the project but at least works.